# ubuntu installer did not set flag "lvm" on partition table - does it matter?

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, lvm

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a new computer, and decided to use the Logical Volume manager lvm .

The installer partitioned the hard drive into 3 partitions, (1 MB UEFI bootlader area, , then I assigned 1 GB as to `/boot` and 150 GB to `/` which is `/dev/sda3`.

The output of `sudo parted /dev/sda print` was

```
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 161GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                     bios_grub
 2      2097kB  1076MB  1074MB  ext4
 3      1076MB  161GB   160GB
```

Now I after executing

`sudo parted /dev/sda set 3 lvm on`

(because I can) , I get

```
Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                     bios_grub
 2      2097kB  1076MB  1074MB  ext4
 3      1076MB  161GB   160GB                      lvm
```

Which is better? Is The `lvm` flag really important to have (or to not have)?
Did the Ubuntu installer *not set this flag on purpose?